# YA fantasy novel, possibly 80/90s, character with special sight

Tags: story-identification

When I was younger I read a book where the main character had a mental power that allowed him to see in 360 degrees and for great distances.  His powers later evolved while he was with another boy (possibly royalty?) and he could even feel the environment. I remember he had friends who were actors.

It was a white hardcover, and had the quote "Look ***, look!" but I can't remember the character's name.  I'm pretty sure it had a "w" or a "y" in it.
Also I remember the author's info on the back said he got the idea from seeing a wandering boy from his window.

I don't think it's Blade of the Poisoner, as I don't remember any great evil to vanquish being the central plot.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend a look at our [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which, among other things, has some tips about story identification questions which might jog your memory for further details.